# How can I make an ES6 named export for parts of an object without exporting the whole object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Here's a JavaScript object I'm working with:

```
const tree = {
  birdhouse: {
    inspectNest: () => 'eggs'
  },
  ...
}
```

I want the world to have access to the `inspectNest` function tucked into the middle there, but for hand-wavy reasons I do not want to give my consumers the entire `tree` object. I was hoping I could do something like this as a named export:

```
export { tree.birdhouse.inspectNest as inspectNest };
```

However, including the dot notation to access those properties seems to be invalid syntax.

I suspect  a destructuring statement like `const { birdhouse: { inspectNest }} = tree;` right before exporting may work, but there's another hitch - other parts of my program may redefine `birdhouse` or `inspectNest` as the app runs. When that happens, I don't know if the changed item will continue to be exported with the new value.

Any advice, or is destructuring the best approach?

(P.S. I know `export const inspectNest = tree.birdhouse.inspectNest;` will do the trick, but in my real app I'd need many of these assignment exports. If at all possible, I want to use the named export object to keep things syntactically cleaner.)

Comment: `export const inspectNest = tree.birdhouse.inspectNest;` seems to be the only option. Or go the other way round: `export function inspectNest() { return 'eggs'; }; const tree = { birdhouse: {inspectNest}};`.

Comment: There are probably times you want this, but it's generally more JavaScript-y to export a closure over the stuff you don't want others to see. But you could `bind` the method to the instance and then export.